# Cisco Router Setup

Tags: networking, cisco, router

I am helping a friend set up a network for his new business and am having issues setting up the router.  I am by no means a network expert.

He has a Cisco 2921 router and I have it set up as follows:

```
GigabitEthernet0/0 10.10.10.1                    DHCP used for setup interface (web and ssh) at the moment.
GigabitEthernet0/1 X.X.X.214     255.255.255.252 IP address assigned by ISP for L3 device,.  External interface, NAT outside
GigabitEthernet0/2 192.168.190.1 255.255.255.0   internal interface, NAT inside
```

All interfaces are up

```
static route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/1
```

I've tried:

```
static route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 X.X.X.213 (gateway identified by ISP)
```

If I ping www.google.com from the routers diagnostic screen on the web interface or from the router command line (SSH), I get a response.  If I ping from a machine on the 192.158.190.X interface I get no response.  I can ping X.X.X.214 from the 192.168.190.X range.

Any suggestions on why I can't connect outside?

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn on routing:

```
(conf)# ip routing
```

If that's not it, then you seriously need to post your entire configuration for people to look at. There's too many things that could go wrong to pull it out of thin air.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your main problem check NAT:
show ip nat translations
show ip nat statistics
debug ip nat

Check ACL used in NAT statement to see if there are matches.
sh ip access-list

Pls be adviced to not use broadcast media in a static route. Always combine it with next hop IP address. Otherwise router will rely on proxy-arp to get next hop. That is usually turned off by ISP.

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/1 X.X.X.213 name Default